# How exactly does the radar work?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

There are bits and pieces on the topic, but haven't seen a comprehensive description.

1. Three layers – What are the distances? Is the distance of the outer infinite?
2. Color – Brighter red indicates more enemies, or distance, or level (above or below)?
3. Showing up on the radar – Does firing your weapon make you show up brighter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If it is showing in the center, they're right next to you (any direction horizontally); if showing in the cone, they're close (within most blaster fire range); if it is just showing the outer circle/arc, they can be very far away (usually only effectively reachable by long range weapons). (I don't have the exact meter ranges.)
2. Brighter red indicates more recent or louder events. If you hear something, it starts red and fades until the next action. If they're sprinting (which most users do constantly) it will stay the same color.
3. The following makes you show on enemy radar:

   - Sprinting (the Scout trait can nullify this)
   - Firing (the upgraded level 2 Scout trait can nullify this)
   - Being a hero/villain/vehicle
   - Being scanned by a droid or Scan Pulse

The radar indicates only 2D space. There is nothing to indicate height difference (above/below) at all.

Answer (score 0):

Center circle: They are very close, possible right next to you
Cone: They are close enough for most weapons fire (except for the CA-87 and some grenades)
Outer arcs: They are too far for anything except snipers (Cycler Rifle, Pulse Cannon, T-21B, Homing shot, Ion Torpedo)

Heroes, droids, turrets, and vehicles are represented with a dot (Except for the AT-AT)

The more transparent an area is, the farther they are from you vertically.

Comment: This is mostly the same as the accepted answer, except for the last bit about the transparent area indicating height. Given that the other answer disagrees, do you have any evidence of this?

Comment: @DCShannon sorry for taking so long to answer, on Endor, when you are on the tree houses near the second uplinks, and a stormtooper is below or above you, the transperency of the red area changes